# How to show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-2}a_n<\infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-2}\sum_1^n a_j=0$?

Tags: analysis, inequality

I'm trying to show the following.

> Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N^*}$, where $\mathbb N^*$ is the set of all positive natural numbers, be a sequence of nonnegative real numbers. If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-2}a_n<\infty$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-2}\sum_1^n a_j=0$.

My attempt was

Let $A = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-2}a_n$. Fix $\epsilon>0$. Choose $T\in\mathbb N$ such that $A<T\epsilon$. Fix $n\in\mathbb N^*$ such that $n\geq T^2$. I should show that $n^{-2}\sum_1^n a_j<\epsilon$.

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^n a_j
 &= \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^{T^2}a_j
  + \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=T^2+1}^n a_j \\
 &\leq \frac{1}{T^2}\sum_{j=1}^{T^2}\frac{a_j}{T^2}
     + \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=T^2+1}^n a_j \\
 &\leq \frac{1}{T^2}\sum_{j=1}^{T^2}\frac{a_j}{j^2}
     + \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=T^2+1}^n a_j \\
 &\leq \frac{A}{T^2} + \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=T^2+1}^n a_j \\
 &\leq \frac{A}{T} + \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=T^2+1}^n a_j \\
 &< \epsilon + \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=T^2+1}^n a_j.
\end{split}$$

But now what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any given $k$ one has
$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{-2}\sum_{j=1}^k a_j=0$, so it suffices to show that given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $k$ such that if $n$ is large enough then we have
$$n^{-2}\sum_{j = k+1}^n a_j < \epsilon \tag{1}$$
But notice that
$$n^{-2}\sum_{j = k+1}^n a_j \leq \sum_{j = k+1}^n {a_j \over j^2}
\leq  \sum_{j = k+1}^{\infty} {a_j \over j^2} \tag{2}$$
Since the overall sum of nonnegative numbers $\sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} {a_j \over j^2}$ is finite, the right-hand sum in $(2)$ is less than $\epsilon$ if $k$ is large enough (as soon as $n > k$), and we are done.